# How to pass AWS SAM deploy a list of capablities?

Tags: aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I'm trying to pass multiple capabilities to `sam deploy`

```
sam deploy --guided --capabilities "CAPABILITY_IAM CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND"
```

I have tried different forms of this, essentially encoding the list as an array with `"[CAPABILITY_IAM, CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND]"`, and makeing them strings `"[\"CAPABILITY_IAM\", \"CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND\"]"`

Every time it gets to the listed capablities in the process, the only thing that is listed is `CAPABILITY_IAM`

The documentation says that `--capabilities` takes a list. What does a list of capabilities look like?

Comment: Have you tried `sam deploy --guided --capabilities "CAPABILITY_IAM, CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND"` already?

Comment: @Dunedan I have now, no dice

Comment: I am able to get multiple capablities to work via the `samconfig.toml` with the line `capabilities = "CAPABILITY_IAM CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND"` but I can't find the correct syntax for the command line switch

Answer (score 13):

While it's all but obvious, what you have to do is to provide the capabilities unquoted like this:

```
sam deploy --guided --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND
```

The same applies to providing multiple values for `--notification-arns` and `--tags` as well.

I'm not sure why the AWS SAM CLI developers decided to implement it this way, but they expect a whitespace-separated list of values for these parameters.

Comment: That's still not picking up the auto expand capability. If I choose 'n' for `Allow SAM CLI IAM role creation [Y/n]:` the listed capabilities are `Capabilities               : ["CAPABILITY_IAM"]`. If I choose 'Y' the next step always looks like `Capabilities [['CAPABILITY_IAM']]:`, and it ends up with the same capabilities listed.

Comment: Did you try running it without `--guided`? When I did that the summary showed me both capabilities.

Comment: If I'm not going to use `--guided` then I can just set it in the `samconfig.toml`. This seems like a bug with the guided functionality

Answer (score -1):

Either of following should work :

sam deploy --guided --capabilities=['CAPABILITY_IAM', 'CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM']

sam deploy --guided --capabilities=["CAPABILITY_IAM", "CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM"]